# Pagination with graphql and django

Tags: reactjs, django, pagination, graphql

I am using react(fe), Django (be) and graphql. Currently I send request when I reach bottom of my page to fetch more "posts" to my infinite scrolling feed.

In django-graphene, this would work like
Return `Post.objects.all() [offset, offset+limit]`. But what should I do if for example, my return statement weren't as easy as just fetching all posts? What if I need to return the posts in a sorted way that they aren't already in the DB? Right now, I am doing it like
Return `custom_sort(Post.objects.all())[offset, offset+limit]`. Still working, but I need to sort them on every request (I think, if Django isn't cashing it). How would one do this so I only need to sort them once, and then save those values for say a minute so I don't need to sort them every time I request?

Comment: Have you seen the [`order_by` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) method of a queryset?...

Comment: Yes I am aware of that one but I was thinking about more complex stuff. Like say I would like to do a sorting which would implement a machine learning algoritm to show me posts that are relevant for a user. Like Instagram explore. Then i suppose that sorting has to happen in django. And the way I do my requests right now, I need to do that sorting on every request, which just feels wrong.

Comment: In that case you are a bit mistaken how they show recommendations. Why even calculate these on each request? All these algrotihms that are used by social media platforms run periodically and store their results in the database which is used for the query. They don't cache the complete results or calculate them on each request (which would be **very costly** for them, not to mention the computing power they will require would be **enormous** and not feasible).

Comment: How would this be implemented in a relative intermediate way or is this something you only tend to do when the datasets are becoming really big? If this way is to hard, is the way I am doing it the most efficient as it could get before moving on to storing results in database?